# Why am I getting calculated padding input size per channel smaller than kernel size?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have the following model but its returning an error. Not sure why. I have tried googling but not found anything so far. My input is an numpy array of 6 by 6.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=0)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*4*4, 320)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(320, 160)
        self.out = nn.Linear(160, 2)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        x = x.reshape(-1, 64*4*4)
        #x = torch.flatten(x)

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.out(x)
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)
```

My input is a 6x6 numpy array and I get the following error, any idea why?

```
RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (2 x 2). Kernel size: (3 x 3). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size
```

Answer (score 6):

Every time you do convolution with kernel size of `3` size of image is shrinked by `1` in each dimension.

So after the first one, without any padding  you would get `4 x 4` image and `2 x 2` after the second convolution. And kernel of size `3 x 3` cannot go over `2 x 2` image obviously, hence the error you receive.

Add `padding=1` if you don't want this shrinking of representation.

You can see more about how the shape changes with respect to `Conv2d` parameters in PyTorchs documentation ([here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html)), see section shape specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you may do and I used the `padding=1` as proposed by Szymon Maszke. This padding is added to the convolution and to maxpooling.

```py
import numpy
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=1)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*4*4, 320)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(320, 160)
        self.out = nn.Linear(160, 2)


    def forward(self, x): 
        x = self.conv1(x) 
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        x = self.conv2(x)        
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1) 
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        x = x.reshape(-1, 64*4*4)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.out(x)
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)

a = numpy.random.rand(6,6)
print(a)
data = torch.tensor(a).float()
print(data.shape)
# data.unsqueeze_(0).unsqueeze_(0)
data= data.expand(16, 1 ,-1,-1)
print(data.shape)

n=Net()
print("Start")
o = n(data)
print(o)
```

Out:

```
[[0.89695967 0.09447725 0.0905144  0.52694105 0.66000333 0.10537102]
 [0.32854697 0.86046884 0.29804184 0.62988374 0.5965067  0.54139821]
 [0.41561266 0.95484358 0.82919364 0.75556819 0.77373267 0.52209278]
 [0.46406436 0.6553954  0.60010151 0.86314529 0.70020608 0.16471554]
 [0.72863547 0.83846636 0.95122373 0.84322402 0.32264676 0.1233866 ]
 [0.75767067 0.56546123 0.7765021  0.35303595 0.3254407  0.84033049]]
torch.Size([6, 6])
torch.Size([16, 1, 6, 6])
Start
tensor([[0.5134, 0.4866]], grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>)
```

By default in PyTorch `padding=0`, so you need to explicitly set `padding=1` when needed.

Comment: Thanks! @prosti, though I get a new error x = x.reshape(-1, 64*4*4) RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 1024]' is invalid for input of size 6400
maybe should have mentioned that I have a batch_size of 100. 

Firstly I do this: X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in training_data]).view(-1, 6, 6)
Then within the epochs, and batch_size batch_x = train_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1, 1, 6, 6)

Comment: You can add another linear layer at the very top input of 100, output of 16 so this will lead to the convolution layer. Can you try and let me know.`self.fc0 = nn.Linear(100,16)`